# Discord Bot Basic Example Fails due to PrivilegedIntentsRequired(exc.shard_id) Error (Python)

Tags: python, async-await, discord

I know I'm doing something wrong on my end because I coppied the example code Discord gives us (first code block found on [discord's quickstart website](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html)) But I can't seem to find what's wrong.

The code I'm running:
(Yes I know an import shouldn't be running code directly ... I just wanted to test the most basic code and I can't get it to work )

```py
import discord
from config import __BOTTOKEN__ as __TOKEN__

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True # this is where the error happens even when the bot has admin privs
                               # if I remove this line, I won't be able to read messages from other users
                               # in more complex versions of this code

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run(__TOKEN__)
```

The error I'm getting:

```
2024-03-14 18:34:51 INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Discord-bot/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/runner/Discord-bot/main.py", line 4, in main
    import example
  File "/home/runner/Discord-bot/example.py", line 21, in <module>
    client.run(__TOKEN__)
  File "/home/runner/Discord-bot/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 860, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "/nix/store/8w6mm5q1n7i7cs1933im5vkbgvjlglfn-python3-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/nix/store/8w6mm5q1n7i7cs1933im5vkbgvjlglfn-python3-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/runner/Discord-bot/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 849, in runner
    await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "/home/runner/Discord-bot/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 778, in start
    await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
  File "/home/runner/Discord-bot/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 704, in connect
    raise PrivilegedIntentsRequired(exc.shard_id) from None
discord.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired: Shard ID None is requesting privileged intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the developer portal. It is recommended to go to https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and explicitly enable the privileged intents within your application's page. If this is not possible, then consider disabling the privileged intents instead.
```

At first I thought maybe the privlages in [discord's dev portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) of my bot might need to be higher, so I set it to admin because that would get all privs ... but I get the same message.

Any insights or suggestions would be much appreciated!

At first I thought maybe the privlages in discord's dev portal of my bot might need to be higher, so I set it to admin because that would get all privs ... but I get the same message.

- Yes I tried to reset all links and tokens after changeing privs incase it needs new token for privs

Answer (score 1):

Sorry everyone ... Turns out I'm *special* (and not in the good way)

I forgot to enable reading messages on the Developer portal (I swear I already did this ... but clearly didn't until now) - you can find this in the "bot" tab. (Yes **now** I understand what the error message above was saying ... )
[image: sc of discord's Privileged Gateway Intents on the developer portal]

Thanks for your patience ‍♂️